# Correct device-icon in network diagram based on configuration or functionality on device

Tags: cisco, switch

Choosing a device-icon in a logical network diagram can be based on two things:

1. Configuration on the device
2. Possible functionality on the device

Lets use a switch with layer-3 functionality as an example.

If the switch is configured to only switch data you could use the following Visio stencil from Cisco which depicts a "clean" layer-2 switch:

[image]

But even though the switch is only configured to only switch data, it is possible to route data because of the layer-3 functionality - so you could also choose to use the following Visio stencil from Cisco which depicts a switch with layer-3 functionality:

[image]

Is option 1 or 2 correct?

Comment: There really isn't a correct answer to this.  Questions that just generate opinions are considered off-topic by the community.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  Yes.

Either works, it just requires that everyone in your organization know what is what.  Some places will use how it is programmed for a logical topology and what it actually is in the physical topology.